# Moving clock arms individually

Tags: arduino, motor

I have as project to build something like this ( using arduino if possible ): http://clockclock.com

The one modelization that came across my mind is to take 2 sticks ( as clock arms ) and command them manually using one ( or two ) motors that will be under them.
However, I fail to find the adequate motor. Basic motors have just one axis in the center that i can control; This would perfectly move ONE clock arm, but the second will just have to follow it...

As solution to create the mechanism will be a great help, I'm still so new at this.

Comment: I highly suggest going on youtube...i’ll help https://youtu.be/rL0_vOw6eCc Watch this, maybe it’ll inspire you to learn some mechanics, which will make your project easier to understand.

Comment: `the second will just have to follow it` ... no ... use two motors

Comment: I watched the video, that was very interesting, however, the mechanism they described do not seem implementable

Answer (score 1):

In the linked page, the arms of the clocks move pretty much independently. It means that you cannot use some simple gear mechanisms to generate that kind of movement using only one motor.

Therefore, using two motors is a must.

Comment: you could use one motor, but then you would require a solenoid operated transmission of some kind

Comment: One could use a complicated gearing mechanism, two motors is the most simple way. But one could be done.

Comment: Thank you for the answer; At least I do know it would be hard to use gear mechanisms. However, my issue is that I fail to understand how even 2 independent motors would move 2 arms placed on the SAME axis...

Comment: Just like in any "normal" watch. One arm spins around a pin, the other one spins around a cylinder - around the pin of the other.

Comment: To be more clear, the hands are solidly attached to the pin and to the cylinder, respectively. It will be mush easier to understand some things if you buy the cheapest analog clock and carefully disassemble it to analyze the mechanism. Or maybe find a youtube video of such mechanism - I did not search.

Comment: @Namrouch, get a thick and a thin drinking straws ... put one inside the other .